# How to return instance of Python's type from C++

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

How to define in C++ using Boost Python function which is functionally equivalent to Python function

```
def test():
    return list
```

Comment: You're returning the built-in function, not type.

Comment: Yes, I know isn't actually a type. Question is how to "create an instance" of it in C++

Comment: Perhaps you should add the invocation to your example: `list()`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @logc Python code is correct. I want to return "type".

Comment: Hmmm, then my answer is incorrect. Let me think again ...

Answer (score 2):

While Boost.Python [TypeWrappers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/ObjectWrapper.html#TypeWrapper-concept) provide a convenient way to instantiate objects for certain built-in Python types, Boost.Python does not provide direct support for first-class objects themselves.  However, one can return the first-class objects through Boost.Python via the appropriate `PyTypeObject` object in the Python/C API.

In this particular case, the Python [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) type is [`PyList_Type`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html#PyList_Type) within the Python/C API.  The Python code:

```python
def test():
    return list
```

is equivalent to the following C++ Boost.Python code:

```cpp
boost::python::object test()
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::handle<PyTypeObject> handle(python::borrowed(&PyList_Type));
  return python::object(handle);
}
```

When mixing the Python/C API and higher-level Boost.Python code, one must use a [`boost::python::handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/handle.html#handle-spec) to construct a [`boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#object-spec) from a `PyObject` object or an object with a *derived* (layout-compatible) type, such as `PyTypeObject`.  A `handle` is essentially a smart-pointer responsible for handling Python reference counting.  The `handle`'s destructor will always decrement the associated Python object's reference count.  Therefore, care must be given when constructing the `handle`, as one must know whether or not the `handle` needs to increment the reference count or if it has already been incremented.  If the reference count has not already been incremented, such as in the above code, then one must pass the return type of `boost::python::borrowed()` to `handle`'s constructor.  For more details, consider reading this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/handle).

---

Here is a complete example:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

boost::python::object test()
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::handle<PyTypeObject> handle(python::borrowed(&PyList_Type));
  return python::object(handle);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::def("test", &test);
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> assert(example.test() is list)
>>> t = example.test()
>>> assert(t((1, 2, 3)) == [1, 2, 3])
>>> assert(t((1, 2, 3)) != (1, 2, 3))
>>> del t
>>> from sys import getrefcount # test for proper reference counting
>>> n = getrefcount(list)
>>> t = example.test()
>>> assert(n + 1 == getrefcount(list))
>>> del t
>>> assert(n == getrefcount(list))
```